# Sympa suddenly changed the domain of all lists

Tags: postfix, sympa

we have on our server sympa with postfix installed. Everything was working fine for about 6 months. On our server were about 100 lists with the format listname@foobar.de Since yesterday the format of all lists is listname@intern.foobar.de (intern.foobar.de is the Sub-Domain where Sympa is running).

When sending a mail to listname@foobar.de I get the error mail from sympa "List "listname" does not exist".

Our normal E-Mail Adresses (surname.lastname@foobar.de) are working fine.

I'd be grateful for hints what could have lead to this problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Did you do any changes recently? Server hostname? Postfix config? Sympa config?

Comment: _sadly_ not. Configs weren't touched for about a month

Comment: And maybe not reloaded or restarted for a month? Without your configs it's hard to guess.

Comment: We need sympa config and/or relevant maillog lines when this happen :)

Comment: Did you change the DNS so that the foobar.de is a CNAME for intern.foobar.de where previously it was a separate A record?  Did you change the system hostname from foobar.de to intern.foobar.de?  Did you change the sympa.conf?
We would need to know more about your Postfix configuration and Sympa aliases file to debug this, as it appears that the hostname has somehow changed.
You may need to explicitly set the hostname in the sympa.conf to foobar.de, using 'domain' and 'http_host'

Answer (score 1):

I think that, for some reason, your Sympa installation thinks the hostname is now `intern.foobar.de` whereas previously it was `foobar.de`.  As a result, emails coming in to `listname@foobar.de` are passing through the alias file only to be rejected as having an invalid domain.

In your `sympa.conf`, explicitly set the host domain:

```
domain foobar.de
http_host http://foobar.de/
wwsympa_url http://foobar.de/sympa/
```

Then restart Sympa.  This will ensure Sympa uses the correct domain name, even if the hostname and DNS have been changed.